# How reliable is KVO with UIKit

Tags: ios, uikit, key-value-observing

> Important: Not all classes are
>   KVO-compliant for all properties. You
>   can ensure your own classes are
>   KVO-compliant by following the steps
>   described in “KVO Compliance.”
>   Typically properties in Apple-supplied
>   frameworks are only KVO-compliant if
>   they are documented as such.

This statement leaves me confused. Can't we use KVO for UIKit objects at all? I don't remember seeing any property being documented as KVO compliant. Despite saying otherwise, I am able to use KVO with many properties. Does this mean that I can't rely on it?

Any insight into this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

UIKit is mostly NOT KVO compliant. This is mostly because `UIView` acts as high-level wrapper for `CALayer`, so when you eg. change the `frame` property of an `UIView`, it will change the layers `frame` but leave eg. the `bounds` property of the `UIView` untouched, so no observer will be triggered for the `view.bounds` path, because it never really changes. And this leads to non KVO compliance.

Only if the property is marked as KVO compliant can you rely on this, otherwise it will not work or break in some weird cases.

Comment: The UIView's frame is not a stored itself as a value. The UIView stores the bounds and the centerpoint. If asked for "frame" UIView computes the frame from bounds and centerpoint values.

Comment: I do fully understand the given reasoning but still UIView frame seems to properly be KVO compliant and that **really** confuses me.

Comment: @Till Mhhh, maybe Apple has changed the implementation details in the newer iOS versions? I don't know, as far as I remember this didn't work at the time I was writing that answer.