# Custom UITextField clear button

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

Is it possible to customize the image of the clear button in a `UITextField`? I have a dark textfield background and the "x" is not visible enough.

Comment: can you post an example of how you had done this?

Comment: Here is the [link to my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39905621/3385411) in Swift 3. It should work for your purpose.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can set your own custom clear button to the text field's `rightView` property. Make sure set the `rightViewMode` property to `UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing` or `UITextFieldViewModeAlways`, whatever makes sense for your case.

If the button's position isn't right for your need, you can subclass `UITextField` and override the `rightViewRectForBounds:` method.

The documentation says the default for the `clearButtonMode` property is `UITextFieldViewModeNever`, but I suspect Interface Builder may set it to `UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing` - Make sure you set it to the "never" value so it doesn't appear.

All these properties are documented in [UITextField Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html).

Comment: This should be easier than subclassing UITextField as Sebastian proposed.

Comment: Note: It seems that `rightViewMode` and `clearButtonMode` have `UITextFieldViewModeAlways` behave differently. The latter won't show the view when the field is blank, whereas the former will.

Comment: The rightView property will only be a view. You will have to add a UIButton and implement your own clear methods still.

Comment: samvermette's comment applies to UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing too.  I'm having to look for a new solution in order to get the usual clear button behavior of hiding when the field is blank.  :/

Comment: Amazing that a 7 year old answer can help me. Thank you. The rightViewRectForBounds with current swift becomes override func rightViewRect( forBounds bounds: CGRect ) -> CGRect

Comment: @Jason Great, glad to help seven years later! :)

Answer (score 30):

You can access that property using KVO:

```
UIButton *clearButton = [myTextField valueForKey:@"_clearButton"];
[clearButton setImage:[UIImage new] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: smooth! does apple like stuff like this? because all other solutions i've seen so far involved creating a new buttom within a view and setting it as rightview on the uitextfield

Comment: @MaximilianKörner I used this and other KVO-s to access inaccessible properties in our application, and it released to the store without any problems.

Comment: Risky to use this given that it can break in future OS releases. I've been bitten before.

Comment: @rounak even documented methods broke sometimes, you always have to count with that.

Comment: **Absolutely terrible idea**. We used to do something like this on UIAlertViews to access the buttons. When apple changed their implementation, all in app purchases stopped working and we were left with weeks of "repair work"

Comment: @JamesWebster It worked from perfectly 5.0 to 9.1 while lots of documented workarounds stopped working in this interval. I still prefer KVO an Apple UI element than implementing a custom objects whats also going to break after time.

Comment: `I still prefer KVO an Apple UI element than implementing a custom objects whats also going to break after time.` - At least when documented features are changed, the changes themselves are documented. This means you can make any necessary changes *before* they break for your users.

Comment: @JamesWebster thats true, but you can also fix not documented changes before major OS releases via testing on prerelease OS versions (especially on GMs).

Comment: You also need to set the image for .highlighted state

Comment: @JamesWebster UIKit is mostly NOT KVO compliant.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6114395/1442541

Answer (score 8):

**Tested iOS7.0 - 8.4**

It is possible to update the backgroundImage of all clear buttons using the following UIAppearance method.  Unfortunately you cannot update the image of the button:

```
UIButton *defaultClearButton = [UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITextField class], nil];
[defaultClearButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clearButtonBkg1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Using the following images, this results in the following clear button:

White background image @3x:

> [image: White clear button background]

[image]

**Note: This will update the background image of ALL buttons contained in textfields**

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

```
let customClearButton = UIButton.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UITextField.self])
customClearButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "custom_cb"), for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 2.2+ / iOS 9+ version of @Brody Robertson's answer:

```
let defaultClearButton = UIButton.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UITextField.self])
defaultClearButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "ClearIcon"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

depends on @Tuss László's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24057010/1531113)

Swift 3.0

```
myTextField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
if let clearButton = myTextField.value(forKeyPath: "_clearButton") as? UIButton {
    clearButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"myImage"), for: .normal)
    clearButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"myImage"), for: .highlighted)
}
```

But really use it carefully. If Apple change implementations in future iOS releases, it would not be work

Comment: using private API is a no go !

Comment: In Xcode 13 still worked.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create a custom `UITextField` that has your desired image as a subview and clears the parent text field when tapped. You disable the default button and add your custom behavior in this custom text field.

This should get you started. If there are any more concrete questions, feel free to edit your question or comment here if it's a minor problem.