# How to add a custom clear button in UITextField?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uitextfield

I want to resize the default clear button of `UITextField`. After I googled a lot, I came to know there is no way to modify it.

So I decided to go with Custom option ie, by adding `UIButton` to text field.I found some code from S.O, but nothing works for me. These are the links which I referred.

- [Custom UITextField clear button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239328/custom-uitextfield-clear-button)
- [Custom clear button for UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713444/custom-clear-button-for-uitextfield)
- [Custom clear button in UISearchBar text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862050/custom-clear-button-in-uisearchbar-text-field)

So please suggest some solution which behaves exactly as default clear button of `UITextField`

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the jake9115 response, you can emulate the clearbutton behavior by using the [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/) callbacks.

You can try in this way:
Show the button when `-textFieldDidBeginEditing`: is called
Hide the button when `-textFieldDidEndEditing:` is called
Hide the button if in `-(BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField*)textField` the `length` of the textField's `text` is 0.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just make a button that sets the TextView's value to ""?

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
_myTextView.text = "";
}
```

Comment: But I want the button to behave exactly how default clear button works.It should appear once user start typing and disappear after clearing.