# UITextField Custom Clear Button

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swift4

I'm trying to implement custom clear button in text field using the solution on [Custom Clear Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28360865/custom-clear-button)

It doesn't work, it shows default clear button. Any idea why? Following is my code:

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let clearButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 16, height: 16))
        clearButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Glyph/16x16/Clear")!, for: [])

        self.rightView = clearButton
        clearButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clearClicked), for: .touchUpInside)

        self.clearButtonMode = .never
        self.rightViewMode = .whileEditing
    }

    @objc override func clearClicked(sender:UIButton)
    {
        self.text = ""
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Comment: why you made override to the clearClicked method?

Comment: try to change name to other or remove override.

Comment: Not a clue, I just copied code from the solution provided in the link which I mentioned in my question. Shall I remove it?

Comment: i suspect it's image issue  `clearButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "clear")!, for.normal)`

Comment: you pasted it wrong because clearClicked method not present in its parent class. just rename it. or better way is to make extension of uitextview.

Comment: I removed it, still same issue. My custom image doesn't show.

Comment: yes @Sh_Khan may be correct its image issue. try this and make extension of uitextview class.

Comment: I've already tried extension which works however the problem with extension is that clear button shows as soon as you enter text field even before you type anything. It should show only when you actually type.

Comment: @Dan then try #Sh_Khan said.

Comment: Sorry it's not image issue as I'm using namespace for image and as I said earlier I've used same image in extension and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned already, in your code the `clearClicked` method should not override as UITextField doesn't have a `clearClicked` method to override.

Anyway, I updated the code to work when using it with storyboards. Added the `awakeFromNib` method which calls the initialisation code.

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    override open func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.initialize()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.initialize()
    }

    func initialize() {
        let clearButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 16, height: 16))
        clearButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Glyph/16x16/Clear")!, for: [])

        self.rightView = clearButton
        clearButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clearClicked), for: .touchUpInside)

        self.clearButtonMode = .never
        self.rightViewMode = .whileEditing
    }

    @objc func clearClicked(sender:UIButton)
    {
        self.text = ""
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```