# UITextField Custom Clear Button - button shows before typing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I've followed extension solution posted here [Custom Clear Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28360865/custom-clear-button)

Clear button shows as soon as I enter into text field and before I can type anything. This is incorrect behaviour. Clear button should only show when text is typed. How to fix this?

I'm calling `applyCustomClearButton` on my text field from viewWillAppear.

```
extension UITextField {
    // Custom Clear Button
    func applyCustomClearButton() {
        clearButtonMode = .never
        rightViewMode   = .whileEditing

        let clearButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 16, height: 16))
        clearButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Glyph/16x16/Clear")!, for: [])
        clearButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clearClicked), for: .touchUpInside)

        rightView = clearButton
    }

    @objc func clearClicked(sender:UIButton) {
        text = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: "whileEditing" means "while the text field has focus". There is no view mode that means "only while there is text". Try `always`. The documentation states: *"The overlay view is always displayed if the text field contains text."*

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch that you are not calling your `applyCustomClearButton()` function.

To do this, go to the viewcontroller that has your UITextfield and call:

`yourTextField.applyCustomClearButton()`

Comment: I'm calling it in viewWillAppear and that's how the custom button does show up but it shows up before I type anything.