# Why isn't UIPopoverController KVO compliant?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm using a `UIPopoverController` to display some content, and I wanted to use KVO to observe the `popoverVisible` property. Unfortunately it seems that `UIPopoverController` isn't KVO compliant.

Could anyone shed some light into why this is the case? Is there some way to subclass `UIPopoverController` and *make* its `popoverVisible` property KVO? I feel like this won't necessarily work if Apple's code is changing the instance variable directly rather than via a property.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How reliable is KVO with UIKit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114261/how-reliable-is-kvo-with-uikit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it's not just `UIPopoverController`. Most of UIKit is not KVO-compliant. Instance variables are directly set often. Unfortunately, there's really nothing you can do about it except file a bug requesting KVO support.

Comment: Do you have any idea *why* this is the case? Do most of these APIs pre–date KVO? Or is there some performance penalty that makes it worth omitting?

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114261/how-reliable-is-kvo-with-uikit is related, thanks for putting me on the right track.