# iOS 9: KVO no longer working

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing, ios9

I have an observer on a UITextView to detect if its content size is changing:

`[_textView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];`

This code always worked to call the following function, where I do resizing of the UITextView:

`- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context`

However, in iOS 9, this function is never getting called. What changed in iOS 9 and how do I fix this?

Comment: FYI - I'm using similar code to detect content size changes for `UITextView` and it is still working just fine for me under iOS 9. But I'm passing `0` for the options.

Comment: good to know - thanks! for the record, using the below suggestion and subclassing UITextView has it working again and feels much more reliable!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do a search for UIKit and KVO Compliance you will see that everyone says you can't rely on it.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612523/ios-how-do-i-know-if-a-property-is-kvo-compliant) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114261/how-reliable-is-kvo-with-uikit).

I don't know what changed, but I think you should just subclass UITextView and overload setContentSize: if you want to know when it changes.