# Implement KVO pattern in UIButton-SWIFT

Tags: ios, uibutton, key-value-observing

I am trying to observe the change in UIButton title using KVO pattern.Added observer in `viewDidLoad`.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var KVOBTn: UIButton!

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    KVOBTn.titleLabel!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "btntest", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New | NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Old , context: nil)

  }
```

This is the method that listens if there is any change in the title

```
 override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
     if keyPath == "btntest"{

      KVOBTn.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

  }

 }
```

I have changed the button title through another button action

```
  @IBAction func changeTitle(sender: AnyObject) {

     KVOBTn.setTitle("testAgain", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

  }
```

The thing is the `observeValueForKeyPath` method is never being called.What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It would be better if you explain more about `KVOBTn`.

Comment: KVOBTn is just an outlet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your add observer code is not proper, it should be like

```
 KVOBTn.titleLabel!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "text", options: [.New, .Old] , context: nil)
```

Note that the key path is `"text"` not `"btntest"`. UILabel dent have a key path `"btntest"`

Also don't forget to chage the check in `observeValueForKeyPath` method

**UPDATE**

This `forKeyPath: "text"` really mater. This means you are observing the change for property  `text` of the buttons title label. If you want to observe change in the text color of the label, the key path should be `textColor`

**UPDATE 2**

I am not recommending to use KVO with UI kit elements. KVO usually use for observing changes in model objects. Please don't misinterrupt.

Comment: yes that was the error but why the keypath text does that really matter??

Comment: UIButton is not KVO compliant for the key "title".

Comment: in the question he asked about a problem and he is adding observer for UIButton.titleLabel not for UIButton to key path title

Comment: @Johnykutty Yes, but your answer only superficially fixes the problem. It's still bad advice to use KVO on a property which is not KVO compliant.

Comment: I agree, but I am not advising or recommending to use KVO for UI elements. Just pointing out the issue with his code.

Answer (score 0):

`UIButton` is not KVO compliant for the key "title".

None of the Apple provided framework objects is supposed to be used with KVO, unless documented otherwise (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6612561/104790), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6114395/104790) or [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KVO.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH16-SW1)). It might work in some cases, but it's fragile and bad code.

You have to use other means to react on label changes.

Comment: that was for test purpose and it worked fine after if changed the keypath to "text" as i was observing  the button title...

Comment: @swiftBUTCHER No harm done if KVO is used like this for debugging. Just make sure the code is removed before going to production.

Comment: ok..that was just for self learning never ever used KVO :)..but can you please tell me when to use these NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New or Old